# What do I do when a user doesn't like my answer so they write their own and accept it?

Tags: discussion

Long story short: [How can one avoid expansion errors in functions killing the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823658/how-can-one-avoid-expansion-errors-in-functions-killing-the-shell/52826323#52826323)

... the user didn't like my answer, so they wrote their own answer and accepted it as the correct answer. The problem is that:

1. The first half of the accepted answer is just plain wrong (and *why* it is wrong is explained in my answer).
2. half of their answer is my *original* answer.
3. The user posted their own answer "yesterday" while my correct answer has been up in it's totality for almost a week.

I've seen other meta-posts suggesting a request for moderator intervention, but I guess I'm worried about whether that's a heavy hammer ... and what would I tag the request with anyways? It's not exactly plaigarism, but the accepted answer *is* incorrect. Am I just being butthurt here over imaginary internet points?

Comment: I'm sorry you feel slighted.  FWIW, I did *upvote* your answer prior to posting my own.  However, I deny copying your answer (either version).  Moreover, not being satisfied that your answer adequately responds to the question that was actually asked -- which is a matter of my judgement alone -- I can hardly be faulted for allowing some time to pass in case someone else chose to post one.  That not having happened, I wrote and posted an answer that I think *is* adequately responsive -- for no personal advantage to myself.  Again, I'm sorry you're unhappy.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for responding, and I understand where you're coming from. My opinion that the answer was "wrong" comes from the explanation not of "what you wanted", but that my post answered the "what was actually happening." That being said, I did miss on the 'just use a subshell' possibility, which was part of your (accepted) answer. I was frustrated about the process, given the detail that I went into, and had actually navigated to the question to ask if there was anything else I could do to supply a better answer, only to discover one that I perceived as incorrect :-)

Comment: ... in short, the answer to my question here is "eurythmia, you're just being butthurt over imaginary internet points" ... so, you didn't do anything wrong, I just got bothered over it and I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's their question, their answer, and their choice. The good news is that accepted self-answers aren't pinned to the top unlike other answers, so if votes have their way, your answer will continue to be ranked above the self-answer if its score remains higher.

As a moderator, I don't see anything actionable here. The asker had their own take on their question, posted their own answer accordingly, did not copy any of your words (although acknowledging your insight would have been nice if they really did base their answer directly on your research), and accepted it (because sometimes it makes sense to accept your own answer as the one who knows your question and your problem best). They aren't breaking any rules.

Comment: That sucks, a bit, but it makes sense to me. Thanks for the answer, and the encouragement :-)

Comment: @eurythmia: What I like to do as an asker when I feel compelled to write an answer of my own, is [give the other answerer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493149/how-do-i-make-a-wpf-window-movable-by-dragging-the-extended-window-frame/5493446#5493446) for pointing me in the right direction. And I do try to make my self-answers as correct as possible. It's entirely possible the asker here made an honest mistake.